# Retrieve the number of 'a' tags between two tags

Tags: php, dom, tags

What I want is to retrieve the number of HTML `<a>` tags that are between specific `<td>` tag.

The example is what I have but I don't know how to put the rest in code..

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML($text);
 $i = 0;
 foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("td") as $node){
 //Retrieve every TD tag that have the attribute bgcolor = #0051AB
//<td bgcolor=#0051AB> NODEVALUE </td>
   if($node->getAttribute("bgcolor") == "#0051AB"){
     $cat[]= $node->nodeValue;
   }
//HERE identify every 'a' html tag that are between the $node and the next one!!
//<a href="path">nodeValue</a>


 }
```

Example

```
<table><tr><td bgcolor=#0051AB>Project 1</td></tr></table>
<a>link1</a>
other tags and text..
<a>Link 2</a>
enter code here
<table><tr><td bgcolor=#0051AB>Project 2</td></tr></table>
codecodecode
<a>link3</a>
codecodecode
```

The result I need: (0 = name of the td nodeValue, 1 = number of tags before the next node)

```
Array => (
   Array[0] => ([0] => Project1, [1] => 2 ),
   Array[1] => ([0] => Project2, [1] => 1 )
)
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: xpath? `//td[@bgcolor="#0051AB"]//a`?

Comment: can you clarify what you say here?

Comment: could you please elaborate a little or share your example html

Comment: The example is now in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll prefer [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) For This Requirement over PHP DOM; Why? it's different discussion.

Below Is the solution of your problem.

Download QueryPath And Just include in your PHP file.

```
require("../../QueryPath\QueryPath.php");
```

Following Is the example HTML for Parsing

```
$text="<body>
<table><tr><td bgcolor=#0051AB>Project 1</td></tr></table>
<a>link1</a>
 other tags and text..
<a>Link 2</a>
enter code here
<table><tr><td >Project 2</td></tr></table>
codecodecode
<a> Should Not Be Included</a>
codecodecode
<table><tr><td bgcolor=#0051AB>Project 2</td></tr></table>
codecodecode
<a>link3</a>
codecodecode</body>";
```

Code To Parse HTML

```
 $tags=htmlqp($text,'body')->children();
 $isRequiredTag=false;
 $i=0;
 foreach($tags as $pr)
 {
 $tag= $pr->tag();
 if($tag=='table'){
 $isRequiredTag= (htmlqp($text,$tag)->eq($i)->find('td')-  >attr('bgcolor')=='#0051AB')?"TRUE":"FALSE";
 $i++;
 }

 if ($isRequiredTag=="TRUE" && $tag=='a') echo $pr->text();

 }
```

Comment: This is just an idea to do it. PHP DOMdocument can also be use to achieve this functionality but due to more familarity to the jquery Syntax , querypath is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Simple HTML DOM is easy to use.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
foreach($html->find('td') as $td) {
       $td_value = $td->plaintext;
      foreach($td->find('a') as $anchor) {
            ...
      }
}
```